# Uniform continuous function integrable?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, uniform-continuity

Suppose $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of continuous functions on [a, b] and that
${f'_n}$ exists and is continuous on [a, b]. Suppose further that $\lim_{n\to \infty}{f_n}=f$ uniformly and $\lim_{n\to \infty}{f'_n}=g$ uniformly for some continuous functions f
and g.

Why g is integrable on [a, b]

This result was given in class without proof. I am hoping someone can help me understand it. Thank you,

Comment: If $g$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ then it is integrable on $[a,b]$. Maybe you did not write your statement correctly.

Comment: I checked my notes and I'm pretty sure I copied it down words for word so I think I wrote the statement correctly. But the statement doesn't say that g is continuous on [a, b] it says that the derivative of $f_n$ exists and is continuous on [a, b] and that the limit of fn=g uniformly for some continuous functions f and g. Does this imply that g is continuous on [a, b]? Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you @JuanDiegoRojas

Comment: If the derivatives $f_n’$ are continuous and converge uniformly to $g$ then $g$ is continuous, since uniform limit of continuous is continuous.